# Не допускает указатель на тип возвращаемого значения в методе

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Столкнулся с такой задачей, где нужно реализовать свой `list`. По примеру из источника я в шаблонный класс включил обычный класс.

```
template<class T>class List {
   class Node {
   public:
    T d;
    Node *next, *prev;
        Node(T dat = 0) { d = dat; next = 0; prev = 0; }
};
    Node *pbeg, *pend;
public:
    List() { pbeg = 0; pend = 0; }
   ~List();
   void add(T d);
   Node * find(T i);
   Node * insert(T key,T d);
   bool remove(T key);
   void print();
   void print_back();
};
```

Без методов

```
Node * find(T i);
Node * insert(T key,T d);
```

код компилируется, а с ними нет и выдает гору ошибок типа:

> Серьезность   Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
>   Ошибка  C2447   {: отсутствует заголовок функции (возможно, используется формальный список старого типа)    Шаблонный_класс_вариант2    c:\users\семён\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\шаблонный_класс_вариант2\шаблонный_класс_вариант2\list.h   101 
>   Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
>
> Ошибка    C2988   неопознанное объявление или определение шаблона Шаблонный_класс_вариант2    c:\users\семён\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\шаблонный_класс_вариант2\шаблонный_класс_вариант2\list.h   99

сама реализация методов:

```
template<class T> Node* List<T>::find(T i) {
   Node *pv = pbeg;
   while (pv)
   {
       if (pv->d == i)
           break;
       pv = pv->next;
   }
   return pv;
 }

  template<class T> Node * List<T>::insert(T key, T d) {
      if (Node* pkey = find(key)) {
       Node* pv = new Node(d);
       pv->next = pkey->next;
        pv->prev = pkey;
       pkey->next = pv;
       if (pkey != pend)
           (pv->next)->prev = pv;
       else
           pend = pv;
      return pv;
    }
   return 0;
  }
```

В чем подвох? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подвох в том, что класс `Node` определён внутри класса `List`, поэтому его нужно явно квалифицировать:

```
template<class T> typename List<T>::Node* List<T>::find(T i) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Заработало, странно что по учебному пособию, где я учусь нет такой информации. Связанно это как-нибудь со стандартом? Учебник 2010 года.

Comment: ХЗ почему этого не сказано. Такое поведение в точности предписано стандартом. Более точно, это "области видимости". Объявления внутри класса не видны вне его и требуют при использовании явного указания на область видимости, т.е. имени класса.